# How to config Rails as subdirectory of Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache

I'm like to config my apache server to run Wordpress on the main page and my Rails app on subdirectory. I mean:

mysite.com     -> go to Wordpress

mysite.com/app -> go to Rails

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost>
    ServerName mysite.com

    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8000/


    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

From Apache:

> In addition to being a "basic" web server, and providing static and dynamic content to end-users, Apache httpd (as well as most other web servers) can also act as a reverse proxy server, also-known-as a "gateway" server.
>
> In such scenarios, httpd itself does not generate or host the data,
>   but rather the content is obtained by one or several backend servers,
>   which normally have no direct connection to the external network. As
>   httpd receives a request from a client, the request itself is proxied
>   to one of these backend servers, which then handles the request,
>   generates the content and then sends this content back to httpd, which
>   then generates the actual HTTP response back to the client.

So your backend will be running two separate servers: Wordpress and Rails. We just essentially change the relevant port and pass the request through. Then the content is returned to Apache and Apache generates the correct HTTP response.

Comment: I insert those configurations but still when going to "mysite.com" I am getting page provided by the rails app and not the wordpress.

Comment: Edit your post and include your APACHE config file

Answer (score 0):

Read this article for explain. [click here](https://www.phaedrasolutions.com/how-to-config-subdirectory-with-rails-nginx-unicorn/)
Two things are needed

> 1. change in application.rb file

```
module YourAPPName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.relative_url_root = '/runthisinrubyonrails'
    # some other configuration code
  end
end
```

> 2. change nginx configuration

```
upstream unicorn_sock {
  server your_sock_path;
}

server {
root <path_to_your_rails_app>/public;
location @proxy_rails_app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://unicorn_sock;
}
location /runthisinrubyonrails/ {
  alias <path_to_your_rails_app>/public/;
  try_files $uri @proxy_rails_app;
}
try_files $uri @proxy_rails_app;
 some other configuration code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't using nginx

Comment: ok other than nginx config you can use rails config part only for apache too.